# If Anaconda comes with pip, why do instructions suggest installing it?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda

I have just installed Anaconda with Python3.7 on my Ubuntu 18.04. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python3.6 by default (but not pip).

After installing Anaconda and reading its documentation, I can see that Anaconda comes with both conda and pip. This is the case, as I can see:

```
$ which pip
# Output: /home/user-name/anaconda3/bin/pip

$ pip --version
# Output:
pip 10.0.1 from /home/user-name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

However, I am confused when reading the instructions from this link:
https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html#installing-non-conda-packages

On one hand it says: " Both pip and conda are included in Anaconda and Miniconda, so you do not need to install them separately." => That's the pip I can see in my commands above.

But on the other hand it says: " It is possible to have pip installed outside a conda environment or inside a conda environment. To gain the benefits of conda integration, be sure to install pip inside the currently active conda environment, and then install packages with that instance of pip. The command conda list shows packages installed this way, with a label showing that they were installed with pip.

So I'm confused:

- I clearly got a version of pip when installing Anaconda and I can see in /home/user-name/anaconda3/bin
- But if I want to use pip to install a package, I need to install pip in my environment using $ conda install pip  and then $ pip install package (all of this in my normal Ubuntu terminal).

I don't understand how this makes sense..

Many thanks!

Comment: It is recommended to not mix the system version of python with your virtual env. So by all means use the virtual envs for all your projects and work and leave the system python untouched, unless you have to. Thus just use pip inside the virtal env (after source / conda activate [envname])

Comment: But I didn't have a system pip before installing Anaconda (i.e. Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Python 3.6 installed by default but no pip). So Anaconda installed pip for me. But you are saying that despite this, I should install pip in each environment I use, is that correct? And presumably, this means that pip would be list in the "$ conda list" command in my environments in which I installed it (with "$conda install pip")

Comment: Yes, although you do not have to install pip manually when you create an environment that includes a Python dependency, the default is to install pip alongside that (i.e., `conda create -n my_env python=3` will also include pip). The documentation is trying to handle the general case of someone who does have pip installed separately in the system installation of Python which happens, e.g., on Windows by default (IIRC). Or if you write `sudo apt install python-pip` on Ubuntu.

Comment: @m93 I think pip is included with an env by default in anaconda. Therefore there is no need to install it using anaconda. Pip for the system versions of python are not installed by default and are not needed for the modules that need python to function. I am  saying that you should keep using the env for personal software development and just leave the system versions of python as is.

Comment: @GlobalTraveler, ok I think I get it now: for the very first install (of "base" environment), Anaconda automatically installs pip and this pip is in /home/user-name/anaconda3/bin/pip. When I create a new environment with a DIFFERENT Python version that base, Anaconda will once again automatically install a corresponding pip version, in home/mmeier/anaconda3/envs/myenv-3.6. However, if I make a new environment with the same Python version as "base", no new pip will be installed, you will just use the same pip (home/user-name/anaconda3/bin). So to conclude, no need for any pip download.

Comment: That is probably correct. But I think anaconda also smartly shared common libraries if they are valid for multiple versions of python, i.e. matplotlib for 3.x will be shared among the envs that have matplot installed and are in the required specs. Don't quote me on this tho ;-)